# How to add cutom class for specifed menu id in main top menu?

Tags: magento-1.9, css, topmenu

Am new to magento 1.9 using custom theme,How to add custom class for particular Topmenu id for playing it with css without disturbing other menu ids.

`<div id="menu9" class="menu"></div>` **to** `<div id="menu9" class="custommenu"></div>`

I dont know which file to edit? I saw `top.phtml`,searched on google but no use for me.I want to OFFERZONE on some differnt colour.Any help pls..

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing old class just add new call to the same and generate new style for it

.custommenu{
background:red;
}

Answer (score 0):

this question answer is completely depand on the theme but I will give you answer as RWD theme.

you can directly change phtml file for this and add extra `ul/li` structure for your requirement. in rwd theme this file located in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml`

for your custom theme you can enable template path hint from admin side and check from which file this menu is coming and change that phtml file directly.

/*Template path hint*/

You can on your path hint from admin and heck the template and its block for all section of the page.

`Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer`

Select the store from Current Configuration Scope drop-down from top left section below navigation. Than go to `Debug -> Template Path Hint`and set it to `Yes`. Refresh the fron-tend page, You will get the all page path.

Hope this will help you.